# Can't figure out the accepted region names for the map function in the maps library in R

Tags: r, maps

I have a dataset containing temperature information for a variety of countries that I want to plot in R. Using the libraries defined below, I have been able to plot most of them. Some of the names in my data set (like 'United Sates') are not in the same form that the `maps` library is expecting (expecting 'US').  I have been able to resolve some of the cases where the issue is an abbreviation, but some countries, such as Serbia, I have been unable to plot.  Is there a way to check the list of expected names? I thought I could find them by calling `unique(iso3166$mapname)` but 'Serbia' is an option in that list, so that cannot be the source like I initially imagined.

```
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
map('worldHires', "serbia", fill=TRUE, col='blue')
```

The error message reads:

```
Error in map.poly(database, regions, exact, xlim, ylim, boundary, interior,  : 
  no recognized region names
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map you are using is rather outdated and does only show Yugoslavia and not the current countries. You can use `'map'` instead:

```
x <- map('worldHires')
z <- x$names %>% stringr::str_detect("erbia")
x$names[which(z)]

x <- map('world')
z <- x$names %>% stringr::str_detect("erbia")
x$names[which(z)]
```

The Note from the [function description](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mapdata/versions/2.3.0/topics/worldHires)

This database was compiled in the 1990's and does not reflect more recent political changes. It is maintained mainly for historical purposes and legacy code. The data in maps::world on in packages like rnaturalearth is much more up to date.